# Wifi intermittently loses connection and then requires restart 16.04. Further Difficulty reconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, realtek-wireless

I'm brand new to Linux and I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I like it but I am having serious wifi issues.

Most of the time when I boot up, WiFi connects to my home network automatically and works fine. After anywhere between 30 seconds and ten minutes it disconnects from Wifi and shows the "gray" wifi indication in the menu(?) bar in the top right. At this point, when I open the networking menu it still shows my network with strong signal. I select my network again and it attempts to reconnect. This time, it does not work again, the wifi indicator likes like a white outline of a slice of pie, and my network is shown in the networking menu but the signal indicator is gray and empty. If I turn off wifi and turn it on again, the wifi says "device not ready" and requires a reboot.

After rebooting, sometimes I am still unable to connect to wifi, but usually it fixes things for a few minutes only for the problem to begin again.

In windows 10 wifi works fine, and ethernet works in ubuntu as well. Here is the wifi script that I hope is helpful. http://pastebin.com/N9tr8FcZ

I have looked on the other questions but most of them seem to be on 14.04 or they differ in what happens in the networking menu after losing wifi.

I tried downloading a different driver. I believe it was rtltek or something similar but that only made my wifi options disappear completely and only ethernet being listed.

Thanks for the help and sorry if this is a noob question or poorly asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless_info contains some interesting things. First, this:

> iw reg get ########################
>
> Region: America/Chicago (based on set time zone)
>   country 00: DFS-UNSET

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set US
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not United States. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=US
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, we see:

```
[    9.503833] Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw_new.bin
[    9.504445] rtlwifi: channel plan 0x20
[    9.504448] rtlwifi: country code 11
[    9.506227] rtl8192ee 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw_new.bin failed with error -2
[    9.506232] Firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eefw_new.bin not available
```

Evidently, your driver would like to have the "new" version but it isn't available. Let's install it and see if it helps. With a temporary working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new/firmware/rtlwifi
sudo cp  *  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi
```

After these changes, reboot and tell us if the performance is improved.